# json decode including http request in php+curl

Tags: php, mysql, json, curl

I am working on php. I want to send `http` request to the ibeacon cloud & retrieve some data from cloud & want to store it in mysql database.

Comment: What is your precise question? Could you explain what you expect to see and what you are getting now?

Comment: function is `curl_init()` not `curl init()`.First find out the errors and try to solve them or at least write the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
    <?php include "connection.php"; 
    $ch = curl_init();//instead of $ch = curl init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, "https://cloud.estimote.com/v1/beacons"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "achopra-smu-edu-sg-s-your iuw:10e891270177480e7443148908d0afa3"); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Accept: application/json")); 
    $output = curl_exec($ch); 

    print_r($output);
   //perform task based on response


      $json=json_decode($output,true));//based on key available in response.
        $major = $json['major']; 
           $battery = $json['battery'];
           $AdvertisingInterval = $json['Advertising Interval'];
           $BroadcastingPower = $json['BroadcastingPower']; 
           $value = "INSERT INTO 
         battery_level(major,battery,AdvertisingInterval,BroadcastingPower)VALUES('".$major."''".$battery."''".$AdvertisingInterval."''".$BroadcastingPower."')"; 
    echo $value; 
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$value); 
    if(!result) { die ("could not insert data :  " . PHP_EOL.mysqli_connect_errno());
                    }else{

echo "Insert data successfully\n"; curl_close($ch); ?>
}
```

Comment: @ArpitaChopra your insert sql is wrong and output is json data you need to decode output with `$json=json_decode($output,true)) ` then use this array to insert.

Comment: @ArpitaChopra `{"error":"Unauthorized"}`, this means credentials are wrong.